# Spring: how to manage databases merge with @Async

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous

I have a Spring Boot application with an `@Async` API implementation to manage large computations and store some states.

**Simplified synthesis:**

- Controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/do")
public void doSomething(@RequestBody @Valid MyDto myDto) {
    this.service.do(myDto);
}
```

- Service

```java
 @Async("asyncExecutor")
public void do(MyDto myDto) {
     doSomething(myDto);
     this.anotherService.mergeInDatabase(myDto);
}
```

- Another service:

```java
@Transactional
public Object mergeInDatabase(MyDto myDto) {
       // ...
       Object o = this.repository.findByName(myDto.getName());
       if (o == null) {
            Data newData = new Data();
            return this.repository.save(newData);
       }
       // ...
}
```

There is a problem to manage asynchronous call and database integrity.
Sometimes, `this.repository.findByName(myDto.getName())` returns 2 objects because two threads have previously called `this.repository.save(newData);` at the same time.

As you see, I tried to add `@Transactional` because I thought it could solve that problem.
Should I need to add `synchronized` or another kind of synchronization, or there is another mechanism to manage database integrity (unique keys, indexes, etc.) for asynchronous processes in Spring Boot ?

**Edit:**

- I decided to catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` and modify my entity with `@Column(unique = true)` to keep uniqueness of some data.
- `@Transactional` has been removed as it is without effect on multi-threading operations.
- `synchronized` has not be choosen due to potential loss of performance.

So, I "reversed" the code in that way (pseudo-code):

```
public Object mergeInDatabase(MyDto myDto) {
try {
   Data newData = new Data(myDto);
   return this.repository.save(newData);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
   // The data already exists, following the DB constraints
   Data existingData = this.repository.findByName(myDto.getName());
   // ... Update appropriate fields in existingData here ...
   return this.repository.save(existingData);
}
```

I am not really fan of this solution, but it works as expected. If you have a better approach, I'll try it.

Comment: From an DevOps point of view: You could clone the incomming database in the target database (in different tables) and use plain sql to merge (`INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM Z`). This way you have 100% performance and respect the ACID rules. As soon as you confirm the merge is finished, you could remove the clone-tables. Is the wording merge correct? Looks more like a replication.